# Can a binary output model with auc 0.5 be perfectly calibrated?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, reliability, calibration

I am reading up on model calibration and I stumbled upon [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/classifier-calibration-7d0be1e05452). To quote:

> We can have a perfectly accurate model that is not calibrated at all and, on the other hand, a model that is no better than random, which is perfectly calibrated nonetheless.

Which, I don't think makes sense. I think if the model is no better than random than the reliability curve would be a horizontal line placed on the y-axis at the overall percentage value of % of positive examples in the entire dataset. However, I am not sure if I am right.

Can somebody please clear up the air?

Answer (score 1):

Upon thinking about it further it makes sense. The dataset needs to have an equal number of each class (half each in case of binary labels) in it and then a random predictor that predicts all classes with equal probability is perfectly calibrated and would have an auc of 0.5

Comment: The dataset does not need to have an equal number of each class. If, for example, 10% of data points are positive, a model that always produces 10% is calibrated (the model probability reflects the true probability) but still random.

Comment: Yes. Thank makes perfect sense. Thank you!